# terraform inline function errors with Invalid Character

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to add the below in my inline function to setup my hostname , update resolv.conf and add an IP to the /etc/hosts. This works fine if i just use it to set the hostname, but errors out with the below when i try to execute the rest.

```
inline = [
  "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --static ${format("%s%s", self.tags["Name"], ".mydomain.com")}",
  "sudo sed -i.bak "1s/.*/search mydomain.com mydomain.local/" /etc/resolv.conf",
  "echo -e "192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"
]
```

Terraform plan output

```
  on main.tf line 52, in resource "aws_instance" "temp":
  50: 
  51: 
  52:       "sudo sed -i.bak "1s/.*/search mydomain.com mydomain.local/" /etc/resolv.conf",

Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.


Error: Invalid character

  on main.tf line 53, in resource "aws_instance" "temp":
  53:       "echo -e "192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"

This character is not used within the language.


Error: Invalid character

  on main.tf line 53, in resource "aws_instance" "temp":
  53:       "echo -e "192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"

This character is not used within the language.


Error: Invalid character

  on main.tf line 53, in resource "aws_instance" "temp":
  53:       "echo -e "192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"

This character is not used within the language.
```

Any thoughts ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try escaping, like `"echo -e \"192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting\" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"` or this way: `"echo -e '192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting' | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"

Comment: @BrunoCriado - Thanks . yes i did try. they dont seem to work (both the single quote and escape char for the ") . I get the below

```
Error: Missing item separator

  on main.tf line 53, in resource "aws_instance" "temp":
  51: 
  52: 
  53:       "sudo sed -i.bak '1s/.*/search mydomain.com mydomain.local/' /etc/resolv.conf",

Expected a comma to mark the beginning of the next item.
```

Answer (score 1):

You commands are not getting populated & executed correctly. Just escape them properly.

```
inline = [
  "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --static ${format("%s%s", self.tags[\"Name\"], \".mydomain.com\")}",
  "sudo sed -i.bak "1s/.*/search mydomain.com mydomain.local/" /etc/resolv.conf",
  "echo -e \"192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting \" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use other Terraform language features to transform your collection to be a suitable shape for inline

```
inline = flatten([
 "sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --static ${format("%s%s", self.tags["Name"], 
 ".mydomain.com")}",
 "sudo sed -i.bak "1s/.*/search mydomain.com mydomain.local/" /etc/resolv.conf",
 "echo -e "192.168.1.1\ttesting.mydomain.com\ttesting" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > 
 /dev/null"
])
```

Comment: The flatten option does not seem to work either

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent this by adding a file provisioner , adding the 2 lines to rile provisioner as a script and remote execute this. Was trying to avoid this as use a single inline remote exec provisioner, but just sharing what worked